# Are RMI Registry and RMI Server have different port numbers?

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

My impression about RMI is as if they are different servers. I write an Interface as:

```
package pack;
import java.rmi.*;

public interface AddI extends Remote
{
        public int add(int x, int y) throws Exception;
}
```

The class whose object to be served as:

```
package pack;
import java.rmi.server.*;
public class AddC extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddI
{
        public AddC() throws Exception
        {
                super();
        }
        public int add(int x, int y)
        {
                int i = 2;
                while(i>0);
                return x+y;
        }
}
```

I want the add() method of above class to get stuck in while loop.

I write a Server program as:

```
package pack;
import java.rmi.*;
public class Server
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                AddC obj = new AddC();
                Naming.rebind("rmi://10.100.11.238:1099/ADD", obj);
                System.out.println("Server Started");
        }
}
```

Then client program:

```
package pack;
import java.rmi.*;
public class Client
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                AddI obj = (AddI)Naming.lookup("rmi://10.100.11.238:1099/ADD");
                int n = obj.add(5, 4);
                System.out.println(n);
        }
}
```

I started rmiregistry at port 1099 and run nmap command as:

```
$ nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-24 15:14 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
80/tcp   open  http
1099/tcp open  rmiregistry
```

I already have a web server running in my system. Then I run server program as:

```
$java pack.Server
```

Then after I run client in different machine as:

```
$java pack.Client
```

Since add() method has stuck in while loop so RMI server is not finished yet. In between if I run nmap again, it is not showing any extra open port.

Are both servers different or same?

Comment: You haven't run the client, so the `add()` method isn't running, and there is no extra connection. As you've started the Registry as a separate process, it will use a different port from the remote object.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Starting the server before the registry is pointless. Starting the Registry and the server without the client isn't going to tell you anything about connections. State your *real* problem, if there is one.